# Calculate cumsum from the end towards the beginning

Tags: r, reverse, cumsum

I'm trying to calculate the `cumsum` starting from the last row towards the first for each group.

Sample data:

```
t1 <- data.frame(var = "a", val = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0))
t2 <- data.frame(var = "b", val = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
ts <- rbind(t1, t2)
```

Desired format (grouped by `var`):

```
ts <- data.frame(var = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a",
                           "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"), 
                 val = c(2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
```

Comment: `ave(ts$val, ts$var, FUN = function(x) rev(cumsum(rev(x))))`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Promoting my comment to an answer; using:

```
ts$val2 <- ave(ts$val, ts$var, FUN = function(x) rev(cumsum(rev(x))))
```

gives:

> ```
> > ts
>    var val val2
> 1    a   0    2
> 2    a   0    2
> 3    a   0    2
> 4    a   0    2
> 5    a   1    2
> 6    a   0    1
> 7    a   0    1
> 8    a   0    1
> 9    a   0    1
> 10   a   1    1
> 11   a   0    0
> 12   a   0    0
> 13   a   0    0
> 14   a   0    0
> 15   a   0    0
> 16   b   0    2
> 17   b   0    2
> 18   b   0    2
> 19   b   0    2
> 20   b   1    2
> 21   b   0    1
> 22   b   0    1
> 23   b   1    1
> 24   b   0    0
> 25   b   0    0
> 26   b   0    0
> 27   b   0    0
> 28   b   0    0
> 29   b   0    0
> 30   b   0    0
> ```

Or with `dplyr` or `data.table`:

```
library(dplyr)
ts %>% 
  group_by(var) %>%
  mutate(val2 = rev(cumsum(rev(val))))

library(data.table)
setDT(ts)[, val2 := rev(cumsum(rev(val))), by = var]
```

Answer (score 2):

An option without explicitly reversing the vector:

```
ave(ts$val, ts$var, FUN = function(x) Reduce(sum, x, right = TRUE, accumulate = TRUE))

 [1] 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Or the same approach with `dplyr`:

```
ts %>%
 group_by(var) %>%
 mutate(val = Reduce(sum, val, right = TRUE, accumulate = TRUE))
```