# Summation series in R

Tags: r, sum, series

I am currently trying to simplify this summation. I am new to R.

#### Data

```
Lx = c(5050.0, 65.0, 25.0, 19.0, 17.5, 16.5, 15.5, 14.5, 13.5, 12.5, 6.0, 0.0)
```

#### Summation series

```
Tx = c(sum(Lx[1:12]),sum(Lx[2:12]),sum(Lx[3:12]),sum(Lx[4:12]),
       sum(Lx[5:12]),sum(Lx[6:12]),sum(Lx[7:12]),sum(Lx[8:12]),
       sum(Lx[9:12]),sum(Lx[10:12]),sum(Lx[11:12]),sum(Lx[12:12]))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate cumsum from the end towards the beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50413415/calculate-cumsum-from-the-end-towards-the-beginning)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do:

```
rev(cumsum(rev(Lx)))

[1] 5255.0  205.0  140.0  115.0   96.0   78.5   62.0   46.5   32.0   18.5    6.0    0.0
```

Or alternatively, using `Reduce()`:

```
Reduce(`+`, Lx, right = TRUE, accumulate = TRUE)

[1] 5255.0  205.0  140.0  115.0   96.0   78.5   62.0   46.5   32.0   18.5    6.0    0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a for loop:

```
Tx_new <- vector(length = length(Lx))
for (i in 1:length(Lx)) {
  
  Tx_new[i] <- sum(Lx[i:length(Lx)])
  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution, using `sapply`:

```r
sapply(1:12, function(x) sum(Lx[x:12]))

#>  [1] 5255.0  205.0  140.0  115.0   96.0   78.5   62.0   46.5   32.0   18.5
#> [11]    6.0    0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Package `spatstat.utils` provides a fast version ("[under certain conditions](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/spatstat.utils/html/revcumsum.html)") of the reverse cumulative sum, `revcumsum`, which is based on computing `sum(x[i:n])` with `n = length(x)` (basically @Jan Brederecke's answer):

```r
Lx = c(5050.0, 65.0, 25.0, 19.0, 17.5, 16.5, 15.5, 14.5, 13.5, 12.5, 6.0, 0.0)

# install.packages("spatstat.utils")
spatstat.utils::revcumsum(Lx)
#  [1] 5255.0  205.0  140.0  115.0   96.0   78.5   62.0   46.5   32.0   18.5    6.0    0.0
```

---

**Benchmark**

```r
x = c(5050.0, 65.0, 25.0, 19.0, 17.5, 16.5, 15.5, 14.5, 13.5, 12.5, 6.0, 0.0)
bm <- microbenchmark(
  fRev(x),
  fReduce(x),
  fJan(x), 
  fEshita(x), 
  fsapply(x),
  fRevcumsum(x),
  times = 100L
)
autoplot(bm)
```

`rev(cumsum(rev(Lx)))` and `spatstat.utils::revcumsum(Lx)` seem like the fastest solutions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code:

```
Lx = c(5050.0, 65.0, 25.0, 19.0, 17.5, 16.5, 15.5, 14.5, 13.5, 12.5, 6.0, 0.0)

l=length(Lx)

aa=list()

for(i in 1:l)

{ 
  x=sum((Lx[i:l]))

  aa=append(aa,x)
  
}
```

all the values after summation will be in the list "aa".